# Docker userns remap give permission issues within defined range

Tags: docker, docker-compose

/etc/subuid

```
ubuntu:1000:1
ubuntu:165533:65536
```

/etc/subgid

```
ubuntu:999:1
ubuntu:165536:65536
```

So I am expecting files created by root in the container to map to my username on the host, which avoids permission issues with bind mounts directories on the host.

This works fine, except when I docker-compose up anchore-engine

This creates a named volume with these permissions:

[image: permissions]

The anchore services immediately terminates and exit unless I manually correct the permissions with chown to ubuntu:docker on the _data directory.

I was expecting that the 166531 is within the range defined in the subuid file. What's wrong?

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '2.1'
volumes:
  anchore-db-volume:
    # Set this to 'true' to use an external volume. In which case, it must be created manually with "docker volume create anchore-db-volume"
    external: false

services:
  # The primary API endpoint service
  api:
    image: anchore/anchore-engine:v0.8.2
    depends_on:
      - db
      - catalog
    ports:
      - "8228:8228"
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: 100m
    environment:
      - ANCHORE_ENDPOINT_HOSTNAME=api
      - ANCHORE_DB_HOST=db
      - ANCHORE_DB_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
    command: ["anchore-manager", "service", "start", "apiext"]

  # Catalog is the primary persistence and state manager of the system
  catalog:
    image: anchore/anchore-engine:v0.8.2
    depends_on:
      - db
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: 100m
    expose:
      - 8228
    environment:
      - ANCHORE_ENDPOINT_HOSTNAME=catalog
      - ANCHORE_DB_HOST=db
      - ANCHORE_DB_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
    command: ["anchore-manager", "service", "start", "catalog"]
  queue:
    image: anchore/anchore-engine:v0.8.2
    depends_on:
      - db
      - catalog
    expose:
      - 8228
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: 100m
    environment:
      - ANCHORE_ENDPOINT_HOSTNAME=queue
      - ANCHORE_DB_HOST=db
      - ANCHORE_DB_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
    command: ["anchore-manager", "service", "start", "simplequeue"]
  policy-engine:
    image: anchore/anchore-engine:v0.8.2
    depends_on:
      - db
      - catalog
    expose:
      - 8228
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: 100m
    environment:
      - ANCHORE_ENDPOINT_HOSTNAME=policy-engine
      - ANCHORE_DB_HOST=db
      - ANCHORE_DB_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
    command: ["anchore-manager", "service", "start", "policy_engine"]
  analyzer:
    image: anchore/anchore-engine:v0.8.2
    depends_on:
      - db
      - catalog
    expose:
      - 8228
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: 100m
    environment:
      - ANCHORE_ENDPOINT_HOSTNAME=analyzer
      - ANCHORE_DB_HOST=db
      - ANCHORE_DB_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
    volumes:
      - /analysis_scratch
    command: ["anchore-manager", "service", "start", "analyzer"]
  db:
    image: "postgres:9"
    volumes:
      - anchore-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
    expose:
      - 5432
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: 100m
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
```

Logs from one of the stopped containers:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yosai/core/conf/yosaisettings.py:100: YAMLLoadWarning: calling yaml.load() without Loader=... is deprecated, as the default Loader is unsafe. Please read https://msg.pyyaml.org/load for full details.
  config = yaml.load(stream)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/twistd", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 31, in run
    app.run(runApp, ServerOptions)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 674, in run
    runApp(config)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 25, in runApp
    runner.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 383, in run
    self.logger.start(self.application)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 184, in start
    observer = self._observerFactory()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anchore_engine/subsys/twistd_logger.py", line 14, in logger
    f = logfile.LogFile(thefile, '/var/log/', rotateLength=10000000, maxRotatedFiles=10)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/logfile.py", line 170, in __init__
    BaseLogFile.__init__(self, name, directory, defaultMode)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/logfile.py", line 45, in __init__
    self._openFile()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/logfile.py", line 175, in _openFile
    BaseLogFile._openFile(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/logfile.py", line 85, in _openFile
    self._file = open(self.path, "wb+", 0)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/anchore/anchore-api.log'
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] Loading DB routines from module (anchore_engine)
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.util.db/connect_database()] [INFO] DB params: {"db_connect_args": {"connect_timeout": 86400}, "db_pool_size": 30, "db_pool_max_overflow": 100, "db_echo": false, "db_engine_args": null}
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.util.db/connect_database()] [INFO] DB connection configured: True
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.util.db/connect_database()] [INFO] DB attempting to connect...
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.util.db/connect_database()] [INFO] DB connected: True
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.util.db/init_database()] [INFO] DB compatibility check: running...
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.util.db/init_database()] [INFO] DB compatibility check success
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.util.db/init_database()] [INFO] DB post actions: running...
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] DB version and code version in sync.
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] Starting services: ['anchore-api']
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/terminate_service()] [INFO] Looking for pre-existing service (anchore-api) pid from pidfile (/var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid)
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] waiting for service pidfile /var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid to exist 0/30
[anchore-api] [anchore_manager.cli.service/startup_service()] [INFO] cleaning up service: anchore-api
[anchore-api] [anchore_manager.cli.service/terminate_service()] [INFO] Looking for pre-existing service (anchore-api) pid from pidfile (/var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid)
[anchore-api] [anchore_manager.cli.service/startup_service()] [INFO] starting service: anchore-api
[anchore-api] [anchore_manager.cli.service/startup_service()] [INFO]     /usr/local/bin/twistd --logger=anchore_engine.subsys.twistd_logger.logger --pidfile /var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid -n anchore-api --config /config
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] waiting for service pidfile /var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid to exist 1/30
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] waiting for service pidfile /var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid to exist 2/30
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] waiting for service pidfile /var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid to exist 3/30
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] waiting for service pidfile /var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid to exist 4/30
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] waiting for service pidfile /var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid to exist 5/30
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] waiting for service pidfile /var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid to exist 6/30
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] waiting for service pidfile /var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid to exist 7/30
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] waiting for service pidfile /var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid to exist 8/30
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] waiting for service pidfile /var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid to exist 9/30
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anchore_manager/cli/service.py", line 165, in startup_service
    raise Exception("process exited: " + str(rc))
Exception: process exited: 1
[anchore-api] [anchore_manager.cli.service/startup_service()] [ERROR] service process exited at (Tue Dec  1 16:30:54 2020): process exited: 1
[anchore-api] [anchore_manager.cli.service/startup_service()] [FATAL] Could not start service due to: process exited: 1
[anchore-api] [anchore_manager.cli.service/startup_service()] [INFO] exiting service thread
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] waiting for service pidfile /var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid to exist 10/30
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] service thread has stopped anchore-api
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] auto_restart_services setting: False
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] checking for startup failure pidfile=False, is_alive=False
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [WARN] service start failed - exception: service thread for (anchore-api) failed to start
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [FATAL] one or more services failed to start. cleanly terminating the others
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/terminate_service()] [INFO] Looking for pre-existing service (anchore-api) pid from pidfile (/var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yosai/core/conf/yosaisettings.py:100: YAMLLoadWarning: calling yaml.load() without Loader=... is deprecated, as the default Loader is unsafe. Please read https://msg.pyyaml.org/load for full details.
  config = yaml.load(stream)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/twistd", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 31, in run
    app.run(runApp, ServerOptions)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 674, in run
    runApp(config)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 25, in runApp
    runner.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 383, in run
    self.logger.start(self.application)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 184, in start
    observer = self._observerFactory()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anchore_engine/subsys/twistd_logger.py", line 14, in logger
    f = logfile.LogFile(thefile, '/var/log/', rotateLength=10000000, maxRotatedFiles=10)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/logfile.py", line 170, in __init__
    BaseLogFile.__init__(self, name, directory, defaultMode)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/logfile.py", line 45, in __init__
    self._openFile()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/logfile.py", line 175, in _openFile
    BaseLogFile._openFile(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/logfile.py", line 85, in _openFile
    self._file = open(self.path, "wb+", 0)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/anchore/anchore-api.log'
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] Loading DB routines from module (anchore_engine)
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.util.db/connect_database()] [INFO] DB params: {"db_connect_args": {"connect_timeout": 86400}, "db_pool_size": 30, "db_pool_max_overflow": 100, "db_echo": false, "db_engine_args": null}
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.util.db/connect_database()] [INFO] DB connection configured: True
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.util.db/connect_database()] [INFO] DB attempting to connect...
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.util.db/connect_database()] [INFO] DB connected: True
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.util.db/init_database()] [INFO] DB compatibility check: running...
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.util.db/init_database()] [INFO] DB compatibility check success
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.util.db/init_database()] [INFO] DB post actions: running...
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] DB version and code version in sync.
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] Starting services: ['anchore-api']
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/terminate_service()] [INFO] Looking for pre-existing service (anchore-api) pid from pidfile (/var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid)
[anchore-api] [anchore_manager.cli.service/startup_service()] [INFO] cleaning up service: anchore-api
[anchore-api] [anchore_manager.cli.service/terminate_service()] [INFO] Looking for pre-existing service (anchore-api) pid from pidfile (/var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid)
[anchore-api] [anchore_manager.cli.service/startup_service()] [INFO] starting service: anchore-api
[anchore-api] [anchore_manager.cli.service/startup_service()] [INFO]     /usr/local/bin/twistd --logger=anchore_engine.subsys.twistd_logger.logger --pidfile /var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid -n anchore-api --config /config
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] waiting for service pidfile /var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid to exist 0/30
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] waiting for service pidfile /var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid to exist 1/30
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] waiting for service pidfile /var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid to exist 2/30
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] waiting for service pidfile /var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid to exist 3/30
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] waiting for service pidfile /var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid to exist 4/30
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] waiting for service pidfile /var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid to exist 5/30
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] waiting for service pidfile /var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid to exist 6/30
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] waiting for service pidfile /var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid to exist 7/30
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] waiting for service pidfile /var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid to exist 8/30
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] waiting for service pidfile /var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid to exist 9/30
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] waiting for service pidfile /var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid to exist 10/30
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anchore_manager/cli/service.py", line 165, in startup_service
    raise Exception("process exited: " + str(rc))
Exception: process exited: 1
[anchore-api] [anchore_manager.cli.service/startup_service()] [ERROR] service process exited at (Tue Dec  1 16:32:07 2020): process exited: 1
[anchore-api] [anchore_manager.cli.service/startup_service()] [FATAL] Could not start service due to: process exited: 1
[anchore-api] [anchore_manager.cli.service/startup_service()] [INFO] exiting service thread
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] waiting for service pidfile /var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid to exist 11/30
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] service thread has stopped anchore-api
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] auto_restart_services setting: False
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [INFO] checking for startup failure pidfile=False, is_alive=False
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [WARN] service start failed - exception: service thread for (anchore-api) failed to start
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/start()] [FATAL] one or more services failed to start. cleanly terminating the others
[MainThread] [anchore_manager.cli.service/terminate_service()] [INFO] Looking for pre-existing service (anchore-api) pid from pidfile (/var/run/anchore/anchore-api.pid)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I was expecting that the 166531 is within the range defined in the subuid file. What's wrong?

The 166531 is within the subuid range, it maps to uid 999 (165533-1+999) which matches the uid of the postgres user within the postgres image:

```
$ docker run -it --rm --entrypoint /bin/bash postgres:9
root@d99b2bbb3d48:/# ls -al /var/lib/postgresql/data
total 8
drwxrwxrwx 2 postgres postgres 4096 Nov 18 08:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 postgres postgres 4096 Nov 18 08:39 ..
root@d99b2bbb3d48:/# id postgres
uid=999(postgres) gid=999(postgres) groups=999(postgres),101(ssl-cert)
```

By default, docker will initialize a new/empty named volume to match the contents of the image, including file ownership and permissions. This is expected behavior for postgres. We'd need to see logs of the failing containers to give more details of why you're seeing containers exit.

Comment: Thanks @BMitch I attached logs for more info, there is a permission denied error showing

Comment: @x300n don't have the time to dig deep into those logs, but you're seeing a permission denied in the anchore container based on the volume permissions in the postgres container? Those two shouldn't see each other.

Comment: Looks more like a timeout waiting for the entire stack to initialize. Guessing it takes time to setup the DB the first time.

Comment: @BMtich It works in all scenarios except when ubuntu:1000:1 is set. I actually created another user duplicate permissions to ubuntu and remapped the conf to it ubuntudemo:1001:1 and containers won't terminate, execed into the running anchore container and found it's configured with user anchore set to 1000. Not sure the correlation, I can't explain hence why I created this post. My understanding is all UIDs inside the container are mapped to which ever I set outside, why works with 1001 and not 1000?